# Loading page with phantomjs and casperjs not working on indeed.com

Tags: web, automation, phantomjs, casperjs

Hi I'm trying to apply for jobs on indeed.com assisted by a script written in casperjs but the problem is that when i try to access

```
http://www.indeed.com/account/login?dest=%2F
```

The page is not loaded. Everywhere else is working relatively good. Any questions?

Thanks

Comment: Which PhantomJS version do you use? Please register to the `resource.error`, `page.error`, `remote.message` and `casper.page.onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I'm using 1.1 version for Casperjs and 1.9.2 for Phantomjs. There are no errors :S. Could indeed be protecting itself from phamtonjs in some way? Regards

Comment: PhantomJS 1.9.2 is quite old. You can try updating to 2.0.0, 1.9.8 or 1.9.7.

Comment: Seems reasonable to try that first, thanks, I will come back with the result